# Как в Valley взять тело ответа?

Tags: java, android

Есть такой метод который кидает пост запрос. Метод работает прекрассно, только нужно получить тело ответа.

```
 public void postAuth(String Login_input, String Pass_input) {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    String URL = "https://api.wishapp.ru/auth/signin";
    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    OutputStream os;
    final byte[][] bt = new byte[1][1];

    try {
        jsonBody.put("email", Login_input);
        jsonBody.put("password", Pass_input);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            refreshToken = response.toString();
            bt[0] = response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            String resbt = new String(bt[0]);
            System.out.println(resbt);

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }


        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("x-api-version", "1.0");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String responseString = "";
            if (response != null) {
                responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                // can get more details such as response.headers
            }
            return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: response возвращает responseCode.

Comment: *response возвращает responseCode* - обратите внимание на строку `responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);` в методе *parseNetworkResponse*. Именно поэтому вы и получаете только код ответа. Прочтите документацию и поменяйте *response.statusCode* на что-то, что вернет тело ответа

Comment: Спасибо огромное, буду дальше разбираться!